# Javascript Viewport Fade In Fade Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, viewport

I'm trying to accomplish something so simple it's painful, but I've yet to have luck after hours of work.

I have 4 divs, each with the class '.slide'.  All I want to do is have them invisible, but fade in when they are in the viewport.  If they leave the viewport, they should return to invisible.  Any ideas?

```
    $('.slide').waypoint(
    function() {
        if( $(this).is(":in-viewport") ) {
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 100);
        }
        $('.slide').not(this).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 100);
    },
    {
        offset: function() {
            return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - document.getElementById('navigation').clientHeight;
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Agdax/3/

Comment: What is `waypoint` and `waypoints`?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of what you have right now?

Comment: Waypoints is a plugin that executes when a user scrolls to a particular location (in this case, any div with the class '.slide')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i played a little and got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6n8KX/1/):

```
/*jslint browser: true */
/*global $ */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var invisibleClassName = 'invisible',
        scrollWait = 500;

    function isInvisible(el) {
        var wh = $(window).height(),
            wt = $(window).scrollTop(),
            eh = $(el).height(),
            et = $(el).offset().top;
        return ((wh + wt) <= et || wt >= (et + eh));
    }

    function checkVisibleAll(elements) {
        elements.each(function () {
            $(this)[(isInvisible(this) ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class'](invisibleClassName);
        });
    }

    $.fn.visible = function () {
        var elements = this,
            scrollTimer = null;

        // Don't check too often
        function scrolled() {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
            scrollTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                checkVisibleAll(elements);
            }, scrollWait);
        }

        // Onload
        checkVisibleAll(elements);

        $(window).bind("scroll resize", scrolled);
        return this;
    };
}());
```

Animation is visible in modern browsers.

Comment: Nice work... regardless of whether this answers the question. +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Having trouble implementing it though.  Can you describe a bit how it's actually used in a site context?  I've got a fixed header which I think is affecting the offset.

Comment: @jwg2s It uses CSS for the presentation. Make sure you have two states for the transition on the element. You can make it like spin, flip and zoom in, too. The js only toggles the .invisible class after a certain timeout. It is only horizontal, when I come to think of it, but you can easily modify it.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I've pretty much got it working except I want to adjust the viewport so it's just the space between my fixed header and footer.  How would I adjust the wh, wt, eh, and et variables to accomplish that?  I assume I would adjust them by the height of the header and footer but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: There is no footers and headers in your fiddle, so I pretty much answered your question.